# Visual Studio 2019 throws System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My Visual Studio 2019 has started throwing an unhandled exception "System.StackOverflowException" in one of my projects - The exception seems to happen at random places. First it was at a call to ActiveDirectory and after I remove that code the exception just came a at another place(getting a appsetting)
There has been no major changes to the projekt so I really dont know where to look for the error
Currently I cant debug the projekt because the error always comes when i start debugging - If VS is not open there is still a error that says the following
[image: Error message]

Do any one have an ide to what is giving this error? Other project runs fine

Comment: w3wp.exe is IIS worker process.

Comment: Stack overflow is the infamous last drop in the glass type of problem. At some point the glass overflows, but it's usually not that last drop that is the culprit, it's the millions of drops before it. So the actual point it fails with a stack overflow exception is usually not that important, but how it got there is. So see if you can figure out how a stack overflow problem can occur on its way to the activedirectory code or whatnot.

Comment: The problem disappeared after merging some changes - It cant figure out how the changes affected the problem(it was mostly CSS ) but somehow the it was fixed

Answer (score 1):

A stack overflow will occur when you have a recursion that won't end. It may also happen when you have a recursion that does end, but accumulates many (recursive) calls before it does, since the default stack frame for a .NET program has a limited size.

Either way, you could turn on Visual Studio's built-in profiler and run your program. After it crashes, study the profiler's output to find out which method is called very many times in order to identify where the (infinite) recursion occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a classic example of StackOverFlow exception:

```
public long CalculateFactorial(int number)
{          
    //if (number == 0)
    //{
    //  return 1;
    //}

    return number * CalculateFactorial(number-1);
}
```

This method keeps calling itself and causes a StackOverflow exception. You should check your code and see if missing an exit condition.

Or consider below:

```
private string userName = "user";
public string UserName
{
  get {return userName;}
}
```

Now, the above is OK. However, if you have a typo and the code becomes like below:

```
public string UserName
{
  get {return UserName;}
}
```

This will cause a StackOverflow exception.

More on the exception here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=netframework-4.8